# HTML name/value button attribute not being sent via POST request to server

Tags: python, html, django, post, htmx

I am currently using HTMX and Django to process button clicks within a table that adds the selected item to a list. I am trying to use the name/value HTML attributes to send to the backend with the value being dynamic based on the database information. I have the following form code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button hx-post="{% url 'add-analysis' %}" hx-target="#analysis-list" type="submit" name="projectChoice" value="{{project.project_title}}">Add</button>
</form>
```

in my Views.py I am trying to parse the data with the following code:

```
def add_analysis(request):
    proj_name = request.POST.get("projectChoice")
    print(list(request.POST.items()))
    print(request.data())
    return render(request, 'includes/analysis-list.html', {"selected_projects" : proj_name})
```

This returns None  however. To debug this I tried listing all of the POST requests to the server with the following:

```
print(list(request.POST.items()))
```

However this only returns the CSRF token, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you check request.data ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi `request.data` returns the following error: `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'`

Comment: Can you share your view that you are using inside views.py ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi Yeah sure, I will add the whole view to my original post

Comment: decorate this view with @api_view and then use request.data. This decorator is inside rest_framework so that needs to be installed if you don't want to install it then let me know.

Comment: Ok done, the response is as follows: `<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['0vWW5COwMrQ3xssK3licZ7pwFZasdfDJpy9fsesdLVi1dg1xhmE2ro11Z1ZWNlva']}>` which still does not include the information I wanted to convey

Comment: __value="{{project.project_title}}"__ how you are accessing project_title from project because you are passing __{"selected_projects" : proj_name}__ in views ? Also you haven't checked whether its POST request or GET you need to check if request.method == "GET" then render the form and if request.method=="POST" then save it.

Comment: {{project.project_title}} is rendered using a different view as add_analysis only renders a partial html file. Using the if statements still returns only the CSRF token and no additional infromation. There are no GET requests to the server when the button is clicked.

Comment: looks like a bug: https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/1132 . should be fixed in 1.9 but still doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

htmx sends the button value with the posted data when the request attribute `hx-post` is placed on the form itself.

```
<form hx-post="/form" hx-target="#result">
    <button name="submit1" value="foo" type="submit">Submit 1 (foo)</button>
    <button name="submit2" value="bar" type="submit">Submit 2 (bar)</button>
</form>
```

Here's a live example https://codepen.io/jreviews/pen/PoEJYMX

In your case you can try to do something different on the server side depending on the button that was used to submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<button hx-vals='{"projectChoice":"{{project.project_title}}"}' ... >Add</button>
```

or

```
<button hx-vals='js:{"projectChoice": event.target.value}' ... >Add</button>
```